# utf 8 encoding is not working properly using java

Tags: java, file-io, utf-8, character-encoding, fileoutputstream

I have to print the log to the HTML file with Contains Currency symbols like ￥ ,  € etc
Below is the line of code im using to write to output file

```
File fileDir = new File("filename.html"); 
out = new BufferedWriter( new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(fileDir,true ),"UTF-8"));
```

in Output file 'ï¿¥ is printing instead of ￥ and  â‚¬ instead of €.

Comment: Where do you see those strange characters ? Is the application you use for displaying the log UTF ready ? Do you set the corresponding headers in the html file that enable UTF ? If not your browser does not know he has to deal with UTF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some possibilities:

1. The HTML file is not set to show UTF-8 encoding. Try setting UTF-8 in the browser you use to view the file and see if that works.

If the page is not showing in UTF-8 by default, update the header. It should contain:

```html
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
```

2. Garbage-in, garbage out. Java won't convert encodings for you. You have to actually write UTF-8 encoded characters to the output stream.

Where are your ￥characters coming from? Are they embedded in your source file?

If they are in the Java source, your editor must be set to UTF-8 encoding, otherwise you will be inputting the incorrect characters in your source.

Comment: ￥character is coming from application, fetching it from DOM and writing to HTML log file,
editor is UTF enabled, values are displaying correclty in editor console, only in html file unwanted charecters are displaying

Comment: What does the browser say the encoding is when you view the HTML file?

Comment: Thank you.. Issue got resolved after adding <head><meta charset=\"utf-8\"/></head> during html file creation.